# Can you define tooltips in Dojo wijit template?

Tags: tooltip, dojo, wijit

I've been trying to get a Dojo (1.6) `dijit.Tooltip` to work when defined in a wijit template.

So, if I have wijit template that includes the following:

```
<a data-dojo-attach-point="tooltipMe" href="" onclick="return false;">
  Show a Tooltip
</a>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Tooltip" data-dojo-props="connectId:'tooltipMe'">
  Got to love hovering over links. Sometimes you a get a free tooltip
</div>
```

I can see the link of course, but nothing happens when I hover. Scouting round the newsgroups it seems there might be a problem with defining tooltips in wijit templates, but it's not mentioned in the Dojo docs.

Is it possible to define tooltips inline like this? Or am I just doing something wrong, it seems like the obvious place to do it.

If not, is there an accepted approach for creating and linking tooltips to DOM nodes defined in wijit templates?

Answer (score 4):

Tooltips connectId property has to be the id of a DOM node. data-dojo-attach-point is not an id, it just creates a reference in the instantiated widget.

So in your case you need to assign an id to the a-node and use the same id in connectId. To avoid id clashes when creating multiple instances of your widget you can use the ${id} variable substitution to ensure that all ids are unique:

Your code should look something like this:

```
<a id="${id}_link" data-dojo-attach-point="tooltipMe" href="" onclick="return false;">
  Show a Tooltip
</a>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Tooltip" data-dojo-props="connectId:'${id}_link'">
  Got to love hovering over links. Sometimes you a get a free tooltip
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems doing it this way before. I used script to create them on my page after I had done some other work, maybe something like this will help you out if you use it in the template postCreate method.

```
var span = dojo.query('.hasEntry span').forEach(function(node, index, nodelist)
{
        new dijit.Tooltip({
           connectId:node,
           position:"above",
           label: toolTipLabel
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, a slight variation on this approach works well enough and at least it all stays in the wijit definition. I'll see if any other views come up before accepting the answer but have a +1 at least!

Answer (score 1):

Responding to an old thread here, but just wanted to share a solution for people looking to use tooltips without IDs on their custom widget elements.  It's not as pretty as just using tooltip, but it works.  It uses the "dijit/popup" and "dijit/TooltipDialog" modules.

```
this.editTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
    content: "<p>I love tooltips</p>",
    onMouseLeave: function(){
        popup.close(this.editTooltipDialog);
    }
});

on(this.targetDiv, 'mouseover', lang.hitch(this, function(){
    popup.open({
        popup: this.editTooltipDialog,
        around: this.targetDiv
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/EcLLb/.

I found out that `dijit.Tooltip` widget from the template is instantized, but it does not connect mouse events, presumably because DOM node it attempts to connect to does not exist yet (i.e. has not been added to document DOM tree).

To prove the aforementioned I tried to connect the tooltip in widget's `postCreate` method, when all DOM building is done and it worked:

```
postCreate: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.tooltip1.set("connectId", this.tooltipMe); // w/o this the tooltip won't show
}
```

So you can instantize tooltips via a template markup and then just connect then to DOM nodes in `postCreate` method.