# Can you use tooltips on other Dojo wijits such as ValidationTextBoxes?

Tags: tooltip, dojo, wijit

(Follows on from [Can you define tooltips in Dojo wijit template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396441/can-you-defined-tooltips-in-dojo-wijit-template))

I'd like to be able to popup some help text if a user hovers or keeps the focus on a Dojo wijit for some time. I know that these wijits come with some prompt behaviours such as when they are empty or on validation errors, but I'd like to be able to prompt regardless of the content of the control. For example:

```
<input name="tooltipTesting"
  data-dojo-attach-point="tooltipMe" 
  data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
  data-dojo-props="placeHolder:'Type Something',
  required:true,
  value: '${blah}'" />
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Tooltip" data-dojo-props="connectId:'tooltipMe'">
  Got to love hovering over links. Sometimes you a get a free tooltip.
</div>
```

Programmatic definition of the tooltips works for plain HTML elements like anchors, but nothing I do appears to associate a tooltip with other Dojo controls. Advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically connect the widget to the tooltip using

```
tooltip.addTarget(widget.domNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

`dijit.Tooltip` connects to the DOM node(s), not to Dijit Widgets (i.e. javascript objects), but you can always use widget's reference to its root DOM node accessible via `widget.domNode`.

There is also a problem with your markup: `dojo-dojo-attach-point` does not assign an `id` to the widget (you reference from the Tooltip via `connectedId`). Define `id` property `<input id="tooltipMe">` to do so, then the `ValidationTextBox` itself and also the root DOM node of the `ValidationTextBox` will have the same id. Note that you cannot use hardcoded IDs in the widget templates.